# Listview with objectdatasource Delete not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, listview, objectdatasource

i have one Listview in my Usercontrol & 1 objectdatasource binded with the ListView.
now in objectdatasource's Deletemethod i have taken businessobject as argument but at runtime i am not getting value in my businessobject's properties...

i also tried to use "Bind" instead of "eval" in ItemTemplate. but not getting any value at runtime in my DeleteMethod provided in objectdatasource's Deletecommand...
can anybody help to know weather i am mising anything or what?

my Listview's ItemTemplate

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUserAchievementInfoId" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("UserAchievementInfoId") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidUserIdField" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("UserId") %>' />
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="AwardLabel" runat="server" Text="Award "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAward" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Awards") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="FieldofAwardLabel" runat="server" Text="Field of Award "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFieldofAward" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FieldofAward") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="TournamentLabel" runat="server" Text="Tournament "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTournament" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tournament") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="AwardYearLabel" runat="server" Text="Award Year "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="AwardYear" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AwardYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="AwardDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text="Description "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAwardDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AwardDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

> Delete Method used in objectdata
>   source's Deletecommand

```
    public void DeleteUserAchievementInfo(UserAchivementInfoBO BOInstance)
    {
        try
        {
    Int64 UserAchievementInfoId=BOInstance.UserAchievementInfoId
            objUserBasicInfoServiceClient.DeleteUserAchievementInfo(UserAchievementInfoId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you show some code

Comment: How about showing us your code, so we can see if something is wrong there?

Comment: Retagged it from wpf to asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the business object key field(e.g id, key...) to the listview datakeynames property. By doing this, you can at least get the key value in the deleting event.